# How do scientists measure the spin-parity of a resonance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I have seen many plots and data tables which display the cross-section vs. center of mass energy for a particular nuclear reaction at a given angle. Here is an example.

[image: csx]

You can see that there are a few 'humps', which are the resonances. Now I can [somewhat] see how one could obtain the excitation energy and partial width for a resonance, but **how does one measure the spin-parity (J$^{\pi}$) of a resonance?** I see in most of those plots and tables that the researchers have also obtained the respective spin-parities for their respective resonances, but I have no idea how one could arrive at that.

Comment: You can't and don't get it from *only* the data plotted here. No time to write a full answer now.

Comment: Oh I see. That's good to hear. Please get back to this when you can (I'll be very happy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such information can be inferred from the **differential cross section**.

Different spins and parities lead to different angular distributions of decay products / scattering partners. You find these correlations by using one decay product to define an axis and measuring the distribution of the other decay products with respect to that.

This requires a lot more data than just finding the resonance, though. You need to have enough observations in a suitable channel, in order to have relevant statistics when you only include decays with a specific angular distribution. That's why it was very quickly clear that the LHC found a new resonance, but took a while to ensure it's a CP-even spin 0 state that has been observed.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know of any links where I can read more about methods of obtaining the $J^{\pi}$ of resonances?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan I don't know of any pedagogical literature about this topic in particular. I am sure there are a lot of lecture notes out there covering experimental particle physics methods - you might want to look for lecture notes (especially from summer schools, those usually are quite neat and concise) at inspirehep.net